# additional row character causing problem, while writing data to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

writing multiple data to file, for each row a special character '\r' appending

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(5):
            f.write("hello"+"\n")
```

Comment: Reading-up on `newline` and `cr/lf`and how they work in linux, os/x and windows should help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for text output mode on Windows.  The `\r` character is a "carriage return", which is the first character in the two-character line ending sequence used on Windows, `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed).  If this is a text file that is going to be consumed as a text file on Windows, then this is probably what you want, and Python does this replacement automatically for you (instead of the Unix-style line ending of just a line feed character, `\n`).

You can open the file in binary mode instead if you really want to write only the line feed character, e.g.

```
open(filename, 'wb')
```

Then you will need to write bytes objects to the file.  You can turn a string into a bytes literal by prefixing it with a "b", like so:

```
f.write(b"hello\n")
```